When is a pseudo-abelian category abelian?
Recall that a pseudo-abelian (= Cauchy complete) category is an additive category where all idempotents split (iow every idempotent has a kernel and a cokernel).
Any abelian category is pseudo-abelian. Now, under what extra assumptions is a pseudo-abelian category abelian?

Why are you thinking that this has a satisfactory answer except for "it must be abelian"? Notice that idempotent splitting is a very mild assumption. It is satisfied in many non-abelian categories. And are you sure that this is your actual question?

Because I know that at least when the category is $k$-linear and (object) semisimple, then it is also abelian, see e.g. https://jameshbailie.github.io/Papers/papers/Semisimple.pdf .  I'm just interested in knowing whether there are milder hypothesis. And with due respect Martin, I don't really see what your last sentence is adding.
